# Changing individual image sources with jQuery

Tags: jquery, imgsource

I need to change the image sources of multiple individual images on a site containing many. They do not have IDs I could use to identify each individual image, which is why I need to make the changes based on the current source each image has.

I have not managed to find a working solution to this.

The html looks like this:

```
<img class="card-image" alt="" src="www.url.com/12987237857.an-individual-photo.jpg">
```

Ive found and tried many variations of this but have not found a way to make this change only a specific img src:

```
  $('.card-image').attr('src', $('.card-image').attr('src').replace('original', 'new'));
```

I have done something similar before with hrefs and this worked perfectly:

```
 $('a[href$="partOfOldURL"]').attr('href', 'newURL');
```

Could someone help me out? Thank you in advance!

Comment: As you are having `img` use ` $('img[src$="partOfOldURL"]').attr('src', 'newURL');`.  [Learn more jquery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest using the [`jQuery.each`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) function.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.card-image').each(function(){
    $(this).attr('src', $(this).attr('src').replace('original', 'new'));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="card-image" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=original+1234">
<img class="card-image" alt="" src="https://via.placeholder.com/150?text=original+5678">
```

Comment: This works exactly the way I wanted and is easily modified to change multiple individual images in one go! Thank you so much! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this using [`.attr( attributeName, function )`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/) like:

```
$(".card-image").attr("src", function(i, val) {
  return val.replace('individual', 'new');
});
```

**Demo:**

```js
$(".card-image").attr("src", function(i, val) {
  return val.replace('individual', 'new');
});

$(".card-image").each(function() {
  console.log($(this).attr("src"))
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="card-image" alt="" src="www.url.com/12987237857.an-individual-photo.jpg">
<img class="card-image" alt="" src="www.url.com/12985555555.an-individual-photo.jpg">
```

You can see in this demo `individual` text in the src is replaced with `new` and the updated src is also shown in the console. You can replace any text you want inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `attribute` selector `[]` as with proper `condition`.

As your `tag` is `img` and want to update `src` use `$('img[src$="partOfOldURL"]')`. And `.attr('src', 'newURL');`

Use `^` to match `element` with `href` start with `partOfOldURL`

```
$('img[src^="partOfOldURL"]').attr('src', 'newURL');
```

Use `$` to match `element` with `href` end with `partOfOldURL`

```
$('img[src$="partOfOldURL"]').attr('src', 'newURL');
```

Use `*` to match `element` with `href` contains `partOfOldURL`

```
$('img[src*="partOfOldURL"]').attr('src', 'newURL');
```

Please review [jQuery selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp) to learn more.